Exterior derivative of $P(\Omega)$
I am reading Milnor & Stasheff’s Appendix C on the Chern-Weil construction. In the proof of fundamental lemma it is said that given an invariant polynomial $P$ over the variables $(a_{ij})$, and 2-form $\Omega$, $dP(\Omega)=\sum (\partial P/\partial \Omega_{ij})d\Omega_{ij}$.
I am having trouble understanding this in the sense of exterior derivative (of a bundle-valued form). So $d\Omega_{ij}$ is a scalar-valued 3-form, and I know that for a curve of matrices $A(t)$ with $A(0)=A$ and $\dot A(0)=B$,
$\frac{d}{dt}|_{t=0}P(A(t))=\sum_{ij}(\partial P/\partial a_{ij})(A)\cdot B_{ij}$. While this looks awfully like the expression of exterior derivative above, it is a derivative in the space of matrices. Anyone can help me connect the two?

The first formula is sloppy. If we start with a function $f$ of $y$, which in turn is a function $y=g(x)$, then we should write
$$df = \sum \frac{\partial f}{\partial y_j} dy_j = \sum \frac{\partial f}{\partial y_j}(g(x))dg_j,$$
and not $\displaystyle{\sum\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_k} dx_k}.$
In our case here, we have a polynomial function $P(A)$ of square matrices $A = [a_{ij}]$, and so we should start by writing
$$dP = \sum\frac{\partial P}{\partial a_{ij}} da_{ij}.$$
When we substitute $A=\Omega$, we then get
$$d(P(\Omega)) = \sum\frac{\partial P}{\partial a_{ij}}(\Omega)\, d\Omega_{ij},\tag{$\star$}$$
but we must be even a bit more careful here, as this is an equation of differential forms. Since $\Omega$ is a matrix whose entries are $2$-forms, $P(\Omega)$ will be a $2k$-form when $P$ is a polynomial of degree $k$. (Since forms of even degree commute, there is no issue here with well-definedness.) On the right-hand side of ($\star$) we really need a wedge product, since each summand is the wedge product of a $(2k-2)$-form with a $3$-form:
$$d(P(\Omega)) = \sum\frac{\partial P}{\partial a_{ij}}(\Omega)\wedge d\Omega_{ij}.$$
